# I'm using a html.beginform to when i click in a button i go to a diferente Action, but i need to pass the values that i have inside my model aspnet c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developng a school project using a html.beginform to when i click in a button i go to a diferent Action, but i need to pass the values that i have inside my @model in the view to the action.How can I do that?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ExportToexcel_Click", "L_AccessPoint", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <button type="submit" id="cmdAction" runat="server">
        Export To Excel
    </button>
}
```

Inside that action i will create a file, and to do that i need to pass the model that i have in the view to the action ExportToexcel_Click

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ExportToexcel_Click(dadosPassar dp)
        {

            var ds = new dadosPassar();
            ds = dp;

            return RedirectToAction("Index",ds);

        }
```

And thats my model,

```
    public class dadosPassar
    {
        public List<Stored1>? dados2 { get; set; }
        public List<L_AccessPoint>? Aps { get; set; } = new List<L_AccessPoint>();
        public List<L_Zone>? Zones { get; set; } = new List<L_Zone>();
        public List<int>? ap { get; set; } 
        public DateTime Inicial { get; set; }
        public DateTime Final { get; set; }
        public string? AcessoVisita { get; set; }
        public string? tempo { get; set; }
        public string ApZona { get; set; }
    }
```

**Edit:**
I need to pass my model.dados2 to my view to i can work with that, how can i do that?

Thats my dados2 structure

```
    public class Stored1
    {
        public short ap_id { get; set; }
        public string ap_name { get; set; }
        public int numeroAcessos { get; set; }
        //public int month { get; set; }
        public int year { get; set; }
        public int MES { get; set; }
        public int DIA { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Your `<button type="submit" id="cmdAction" runat="server"> Export To Excel </button>` is not in correct format. Replace this with `<input type="submit" d="cmdAction" value="Export To Excel"/>`.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I edit my question with my doubt

Comment: Could you please post another question with this issue so that It can be answered there as the question been modified then that would be great.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I will do that tks

Comment: Okay I will try to answer there.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron thats the new question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72057759/when-i-click-in-a-button-i-go-to-a-diferente-action-but-i-need-to-pass-the-valu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using a html.beginform to when I click in a button I go to a diferente Action?"

Yes this is very obvious it should redirect to your `controller` as per your code. Because `<button type="submit" runat="server"> Export To Excel </button>` is not correct way to do that. You should try below way.

**Correct Way:**

```
 <input type="submit" id="cmdAction" value="Export To Excel"/>
```

**Output:**

[image]

> But I need to pass the values that I have inside my model aspnet c#

It seems that you are sending nothing inside your `BeginForm` submit action as shown below.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ExportToexcel_Click", "L_AccessPoint", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="submit" d="cmdAction" value="Export To Excel"/>
}
```

Note: Above code will submit null value to your `ExportToexcel_Click` controller as you are not sending anything inside the `form post action`.

**Demo:**

Though it's not clear what your plan is. But if you would like to load this page with some predefined data in that case, you should initialize the `model` in your `controller Index action` then load the value in hidden mode like below:

**Controller Action For Initial View:**

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var ds = new dadosPassar();
            ds.AcessoVisita = "Initial AcessoVisita";
            ds.tempo = "Initial Tempo";
            ds.ApZona = "Initial Ap Zona";
            ds.Final = DateTime.Now;
            return View(ds);
        }
```

**View:**

```cs
@model DotNet6MVCWebApp.Models.dadosPassar 

@using (Html.BeginForm("ExportToexcel_Click", "L_AccessPoint", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input asp-for="AcessoVisita" hidden class="form-control" />
    <input asp-for="tempo" hidden class="form-control" />
    <input asp-for="ApZona" hidden class="form-control" />
    <input type="submit" d="cmdAction" value="Export To Excel"/>
}
```

**Controller When Submit Button Clicked:**

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ExportToexcel_Click(dadosPassar dp)
        {

            var ds = new dadosPassar();
            ds = dp;

            return RedirectToAction("Index", ds);

        }
```

**Output:**

[image]

This should resolve your current issue and guide you to pass values to your controller `POST` method expectedly.