# I would like to pass the values that i have in my view to a action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing a school project using a html.beginform to when i click in a button i go to a diferent Action, but i need to pass the values that i have inside my @model.dados2 in the view to the action, how can i do that?

```
<form asp-action="ExportToexcel_Click" method="post">
    <input asp-for="Inicial" hidden/>
    <input asp-for="Final" hidden/>
    <input asp-for="AcessoVisita" hidden />
    <input asp-for="tempo" hidden/>
    <input asp-for="ApZona" hidden/>
    <select class="listbox2" hidden asp-for="ap"  multiple>
        @foreach(var i in Model.ap)
        {
            <option value=@i> @i </option>
        }
    </select>

    <div class="form-group"style="margin-bottom:2%;margin-top:2%;">
        <input type="submit" value="Consultar" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
               
</form>
```

I already pass some data to the new action, i passed a list of ints, but i don't know how to pass a list of object.

Inside that action i will create a file, and to do that i need to pass the model that i have in the view to the action ExportToexcel_Click

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ExportToexcel_Click(dadosPassar dp)
        {

            var ds = new dadosPassar();
            ds = dp;

            return RedirectToAction("Index",ds);

        }
```

And thats my model,

```
    public class dadosPassar
    {
        public List<Stored1>? dados2 { get; set; }
        public List<L_AccessPoint>? Aps { get; set; } = new List<L_AccessPoint>();
        public List<L_Zone>? Zones { get; set; } = new List<L_Zone>();
        public List<int>? ap { get; set; } 
        public DateTime Inicial { get; set; }
        public DateTime Final { get; set; }
        public string? AcessoVisita { get; set; }
        public string? tempo { get; set; }
        public string ApZona { get; set; }
    }
```

Thats my dados2 structure

```
    public class Stored1
    {
        public short ap_id { get; set; }
        public string ap_name { get; set; }
        public int numeroAcessos { get; set; }
        //public int month { get; set; }
        public int year { get; set; }
        public int MES { get; set; }
        public int DIA { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Could you please edit the question title seems the title as pervious, just edit with your current problem, which model you want to pass in view? with default value or you would like to take value from the view?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I would like to pass the values that i have in my view to the new action, if that's possible

Comment: `"I would like to pass the values that i have in my view to"` So you want load `Stored1 model` on view and then you want to pass this value to `public ActionResult ExportToexcel_Click(dadosPassar dp)` then finally you want to pass this value to `Index` action again am I right?

Comment: I want to load dados2 that is a atributte of model that is an object of type stored1 that already have values and i need to pass that values to my ```public ActionResult ExportToexcel_Click(dadosPassar dp)``` and then to my Index action. @MdFaridUddinKiron Exactly.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I already have the correct data in the model.dados2, i just need a way of pass that data that is inside model.dados2 to the view ExportToexcel_Click.

Comment: You are saying you have the correct data in the model.dados2 again saying need inside model.dados2 sounds bit confusing. Share your current code and where you are having problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"But I don't know how to pass a list of object"**

> You could follow below steps:

**Controller Action For Loading View:**

```
public IActionResult Index(string stored1s)
        {
            if (stored1s != null)
            {
                List<Stored1> model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Stored1>>(stored1s);
            }

            var listDados = new List<Stored1>()
            {
                new Stored1(){ ap_id = 101,ap_name ="AP-101", year= 2021, DIA=101, MES=202},
                new Stored1(){ ap_id = 102,ap_name ="AP-102", year= 2022, DIA=102, MES=203},
                new Stored1(){ ap_id = 103,ap_name ="AP-103", year= 2023, DIA=103, MES=204},


            };
            var ds = new dadosPassar();
            ds.AcessoVisita = "Initial AcessoVisita";
            ds.tempo = "Initial Tempo";
            ds.ApZona = "Initial Ap Zona";
            ds.Final = DateTime.Now;
            ds.dados2 = listDados;
            return View(ds);
        }
```

> **Note:** Here `string stored1s` will be assigned value when `RedirectToAction` will be called from `ExportToexcel_Click` method.

**Alternative Index**

```
   public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var stringList = TempData["dados2"].ToString();
            List<Stored1> datosList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Stored1>>(stringList);

            var listDados = new List<Stored1>()
            {
                new Stored1(){ ap_id = 101,ap_name ="AP-101", year= 2021, DIA=101, MES=202},
                new Stored1(){ ap_id = 102,ap_name ="AP-102", year= 2022, DIA=102, MES=203},
                new Stored1(){ ap_id = 103,ap_name ="AP-103", year= 2023, DIA=103, MES=204},


            };
            var ds = new dadosPassar();
            ds.AcessoVisita = "Initial AcessoVisita";
            ds.tempo = "Initial Tempo";
            ds.ApZona = "Initial Ap Zona";
            ds.Final = DateTime.Now;
            ds.dados2 = listDados;
            return View(ds);
        }
```

**View:**

```
@model DotNetWebApp.Models.dadosPassar

@using (Html.BeginForm("ExportToexcel_Click", "L_AccessPoint", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input asp-for="AcessoVisita" hidden class="form-control" />
    <input asp-for="tempo" hidden class="form-control" />
    <input asp-for="ApZona" hidden class="form-control" />

    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.dados2.Count; i++)
    {
        
        <tr >
            <td>
                <label><strong>Id</strong></label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.dados2[i].ap_id)
            </td>
            <td>
                <label><strong>Name</strong></label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.dados2[i].ap_name)
            </td>
            <td>
                <label><strong>Year</strong></label>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dados2[i].year)
            </td>

        </tr>
        <br />
    }
    <input type="submit" d="cmdAction" style="margin-top:10px" class="btn btn btn-primary" value="Export To Excel" />
}
```

> **Note:** You can hide your `@Html.TextBoxFor` if you don't want them to display. Up to you.

**Controller When Submit:**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ExportToexcel_Click(dadosPassar dp)
        {

            var ds = new dadosPassar();
            ds = dp;
            return RedirectToAction("Index",
    new
    {
        stored1s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dp.dados2)
    });

           

        }
```

**`If you prefer Alternative Index in that case use this ExportToexcel_Click`**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ExportToexcel_Click(dadosPassar dp)
        {

            var ds = new dadosPassar();
            ds = dp;
            TempData["dados2"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dp.dados2);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
    



        }
```

**Output:**

[image]