# Values/Data dont show on View from Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model, .net-7.0

I try send values/data from controller to view.

Model, classes EmailModel, EmailPersonModel

```
public class EmailModel
  {
      [Required]
      public EmailPersonModel Sender { get; set; } = new EmailPersonModel();
      [Required]
      public List<EmailPersonModel> Recipients { get; set; } = new List<EmailPersonModel>();
      [Required]
      public string Subject { get; set; }= string.Empty;
      [Required]
      public string Message { get; set; }= string.Empty;
}

public class EmailPersonModel
  {
      public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;
      public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Controller: i get data from service, values are in model

```
[HttpGet("SendInfoEmail/{id}")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> SendInfoEmail(Guid id)
  {
EmailModel? model =  await _emailsService.SendToUser(reportWithId, ADLogin).ConfigureAwait(false);

 return RedirectToAction("Index", model);
 }
public IActionResult Index(EmailModel model)
  {  

    return View("~/Views/Mails/Create.cshtml", model);
  }
```

View

```
<div class="container mt-5">

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="sender" class="form-label">Nadawca:</label>
            <input type="text"
                id="sender" 
                name="Sender.Email" 
                value="@Model.Sender.Email"
                class="form-control" 
                required />       
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="recipients" class="form-label">Odbiorcy (oddziel przecinkami):</label>
            <input type="text" 
                id="recipients" 
                name="recipients" 
                value="@string.Join(", ", @Model.Recipients.Select(r => r.Email))"
                    class="form-control" 
                    required />
        </div>
        << --  others: subject + messageContent   -->>
    
</div>
```

Problem:

Value in Sender.Email and recipients dont display, but subject and messageContent display correctly

Comment: Can you please post full but succinct [mre] somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Value in Sender.Email and recipients dont display, but subject and
> messageContent display correctly

Actually, you are using [RedirectToAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoaction?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-controllerbase-redirecttoaction(system-string-system-string-system-object-system-string))  which takes route value and action name as parameter as you can see below:

[image]

However, [RedirectToAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoaction?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-controllerbase-redirecttoaction(system-string-system-string-system-object-system-string)) cannot process complex object to pass your value within the controller action. In your request Recipients and Sender itself a complex model because its belongs to another model that is EmailModel and this is causing your null data on view. I have reproduce your issue accordingly:

[image]

How to resolve:

Numerous way available to get rid of null data while redirect from one controller action to another.

Directly calling action:

Calling Index action directly and then we can pass the model value. Let's have a look in action.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SendInfoEmail()
        {
         
            EmailModel? model =
                new EmailModel { Subject = "Test Subject", Sender =
                new EmailPersonModel { Email = "sender@outlook.com", Name = "sender" }, Message = "Test Message", Recipients =
                new List<EmailPersonModel> {
                    new EmailPersonModel { Email = "Recipient1@outlook.com", Name = "Recipient1" },
                    new EmailPersonModel { Email = "Recipient2@outlook.com", Name = "Recipient2" } }
                };
            return Index(model);


        }
```

Index Action:

```
public IActionResult Index(EmailModel model)
        {

            return View("~/Views/Mails/Create.cshtml", model);
        }
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** You can also use [TempData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller.tempdata?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to pass object in that scenario you would need to deserialize object/string into your strongly type model. For more details, you can [refer to this example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72057759/i-would-like-to-pass-the-values-that-i-have-in-my-view-to-a-action/72062073#72062073)